# How to Resize Properties Window in TinyMCE 4.x?

Tags: tinymce-4

I would like to resize the property window (e.g. when we click on "Table Properties") of TinyMCE 4.x. In the image shown below, the table properties window gets squeezed in terms of width and the labels get overlapped. I looked at the DOM nodes, and most of the widths and heights properties of the container windows, labels and inputs are set dynamically using javascript. Is there a way for us to change the size of these property windows?

[image]